# how to change the range of xaxis of google column chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization, column-chart

I am using google column chart to create a column chart as shown below:

```
const chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv); // Extract the data from which to populate the chart.

        chart.draw(data, {
          height: 300,
          legend: "none",
          // @ts-ignore TODO(jpoehnelt) check versions
            titleY: "Elevation (Meters)",
            titleX: "Distance (Miles)"

        });
```

The one problem is the values in xaxis. How can i only show 5 values for eg. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? The xaxes values that are marked in red is populated densely. How to divide into 5 sections? Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for --> `hAxis`

there are a number of options to control the labels on the axis.

to divide the axis into segments,
use the `gridlines.count` option.

this allows you to specify how many gridlines will be displayed,
and thus the number of labels.

```
hAxis: {
  gridlines: {
    count: 5
  }
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  var y = 1380;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
    data.addRow([i, (i % 2 === 0) ? y + i : y - i]);
  }

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 64,
      top: 48,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 64,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 5
      },
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      alignment: 'start',
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working. adding haxis.gridlines.count is not having any effect. i am using 
        google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages: ["columnchart"]
        }); so the chart looks little different than the above code chart.

Comment: for some reason google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages: ["columnchart"]
        }); was not working so i have switched to the method you have recommended google.charts.load('current', {
            packages:['corechart']
        });

Comment: also it was not working for some reason and i found that value.toFixed(2) returned string not number. this was puzzling. i used parseFloat() to convert it to number and it now works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sure, the `jsapi` library and load statement you noted above have been deprecated. see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code). and yes, [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Syntax) does return a string.

Comment: ah..thank you! that makes sense. i will switch to newer version.